# how to toggle/reset event.preventDefault() on kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid, preventdefault, stoppropagation

My requirement is to enable / disable event propagation on kendo Grid.
So i could able to disable as follwos

```
$("#gridReport").data("kendoGrid").bind("dataBinding", function(e) {
             e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Now How to enable event propagation? OR Reset above change?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `unbind` method to remove bindings.

```
// remove _all_ dataBinding bindings
$("#gridReport").data("kendoGrid").unbind("dataBinding");
```

To remove a specific binding instance you will need to maintain a reference to the handler.

```
var myHandler = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };
$("#gridReport").data("kendoGrid").bind("dataBinding", myHandler);

// remove a specific dataBinding binding
$("#gridReport").data("kendoGrid").unbind("dataBinding", myHandler);
```

You can also remove all bindings of all events

```
$("#gridReport").data("kendoGrid").unbind();
```

More info in the documentation

- https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/bind
- https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/unbind

Comment: Handled in same way, Thanks!!